# Clean architecture: separate IO and Core in different .jar files

Tags: java, clean-architecture

In clean architecture the structure is like that:

CORE:

- CoreClass.java
- SomeDAOInterface.java

IO

- SomeDAOInterfaceImpl.java (implement SomeDAOInterface)

If I was supposed to split Core and IO in different .jar files, different projects, how am I supposed to handle "SomeDAOInterface" dependency in IO part? It is only contained in Core part, so I cannot really implement it without compiler error (no class SomeDAOInterface found).

Comment: Move those interfaces into a "common" library, that is used by both your CORE and IO modules...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is far from an unusual design, and there are plenty of examples around. For example Java EE declares a number of interfaces which are to be implemented by various containers. Or Jdbc also declares interfaces which will be implemented by database engines.

There are 2 possible designs depending on whether the binding will occur at build time or at run time.

When binding occurs at build time (common for jdbc for example), you must have an implementation available at build time, for example you declare a MySQL database driver in your project. In your example, it means the the IO project will depend on the Core one.

When binding occurs at run time (Java EE for example), you use a *dummy* project that only contains the interface classes (`SomeDAOInterface` in your example) and not the implementations for compilation and declare to the builder not to link it in the final jar but that it will be *provided* at run time. And at run-time you do provide in classpath a full implementation, containing both the interface classes (`SomeDAOInterface`) **and** the implementation ones (`SomeDAOInterfaceImpl` in your example). You will just have to read your build system documentation to know how to declare that.
Alternately, you can link the dummy project in the core jar, and declare that it will be provided in the implementation one.

Answer (score 0):

If u r talking about Clean Architecture from Uncle Bob then I wonder what the CORE project is?

[image: https://8thlight.com/blog/assets/posts/2012-08-13-the-clean-architecture/CleanArchitecture.jpg]

In case u refer to the "entities circle" then having the interface defined there is fine IF this is really part of ur core business rules.
u would then create a dependency from ur IO project (which is in frameworks or interface adapters layer) to the CORE project which is correct according to the dependency rule.

For a more detailed discussion on project structures in Clean Architecture pls refer to my post: https://plainionist.github.io/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-Scream/